# -Warray-bounds bogus warning in inline function g++4.9.2

Tags: c++, gcc

I am getting the weirdest warning I ever encountered. I have an inlined function in which I'm doing something like

```
inline int f(int n)
{
    int myarray[maxn];
    myarray[n-1] = 1;
}
```

The parameter `maxn` is defined in a header file as `constexpr`. The parameter `n` passed to `f` is ALWAYS smaller or equal to `maxn` in my code. However, whenever I compile, I get the warning

```
warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
```

in the line `myarray[n-1] = 1`.

It only happens using `g++4.9` (`clang++` doesn't emit any warning, as well as previous `g++` versions), and ONLY when the function is marked `inline`. If I use a test condition in the function such as

```
if(n > maxn) cerr << "ERROR!"<< endl;
```

or even a simple display statement as

```
cout << n;
```

the warning disappears (the `if` is of course evaluated to `false`, so no error message is displayed, as I make absolutely sure that `n <= maxn;`).

Does anyone know if this is a `g++` issue? Have you encountered before?

Comment: Curious, did you ever file a bug report?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Will reduce it to a minimal case asap, the code I have it's pretty complicated (lambda is capturing by reference some parameters, plus threads). After I come back from vacation I hope to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like false positive issues with array bounds checking has been reported for `gcc` several times( [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56273) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51721)), for example this bug report  [Picon
[Bug c/59564] New: False positive array -Warray-bounds check with -O2](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.bugs/401565) shows this code when using `-02` and `gcc 4.8.2` and `gcc 4.9.0` produces a false positive (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a56eb5511067b4b)*):

```
int arr[1];
int n = 0;

int main() {
  if (n <= 0) n = 0;
  arr[n] = 0;
  if (n <= 0) n = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

So this is likely a regression or a different form of the bug, you should file a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll first try to put the code into the simplest compilable example (which is not trivial right now :) ) But will definitely do it. Now I'm just using a `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Warray-bounds"` to silent the warning.

Comment: @vsoftco if you could update your question with the example and eventually the bug report that would be great. I could not reproduce your particular issue but I don't think any of the online compilers have `gcc 4.9.2`.

Comment: @Shafik To be fair, the question lacks an MCVE. So I'm not surprised you can't reproduce it.

Comment: @remyabel I will produce a minimal example, however it's a bit complicated, as I call some functions inside lambdas etc, and cannot yet figure exactly when it happens.

Comment: @remyabel a full example is always better but the information was strongly indicative and while not ideal was sufficient.